# Calculate duration through while loop with conditional break

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, duration

I am trying to calculate the time spent out of sight during a behavioural observation. I have a df ([link](https://liveuclac-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ucsaoat_ucl_ac_uk/ERaBBDi1DnRJrHVWESv_ll0Bcmrt5f_MxNq7Tzx7Vl-p9A?e=777ULJ)) where "Out_Sight" stops either if there is an "In_Sight" or if the observation ends ("End_Focal"). I would like to calculate the time out of sight per each focal observation (each has an unique "ObsID" - durations would appear in each row of "foc_summary" as per code below).

I created a loop where the records belonging to each ObsID should be treated separately. The *for* loop adds up time to the new Time_OutSight variable *if* it encounters an Out_Sight and *while* there are no "In_Sight" or "End_Focal" ("stop").

```
df$HMS <- lubridate::hms(df$Time, roll = F)

library(dplyr)
foc_summary <- df %>% 
  mutate(ObsID=factor(ObsID)) %>% 
  group_by(ObsID) %>% 
  slice(1) 
detach('package:dplyr')

foc_summary <- as.data.frame(foc_summary)

df <- df[order(df$ObsID, df$HMS),] # Order focal data to have the right sequence

stop <- list("In_Sight","End_Focal")

foc_summary$Time_OutSight <- NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(foc_summary)){
  I <- foc_summary$ObsID[i]
  print(I)
  
  tabI <- droplevels(subset(df, df$ObsID == I))
  Time_OutSight <- c()
  
  for(j in 1:nrow(tabI)){
    if (tabI$Setting[j] %in% "Out_Sight"){
      
      k=j+1
      while(k < nrow(tabI) &&
            tabI$Setting[k] %!in% stop){k=k+1}
      print(tabI$Setting[k]); print(tabI$HMS[k])
      
      Time_OutSight <- c(Time_OutSight, as.numeric(tabI$HMS[k])-as.numeric(tabI$HMS[j]))
    }
  }
  foc_summary$Time_OutSight[i] <- sum(Time_OutSight)
}
```

The code includes a "not in" function:

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))
```

The code works only partially because it doesn't seem to stop at "End_Focal" resulting in extra long out of sight times.

Could someone help me understand why the code doesn't work? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Add your language tag next time. Done for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that `for`/`while` loops are not optimal or efficient for summarizing operations like this. I think we can simply summarize by group such as below.

I'll demonstrate in dplyr, though this can be done in base R or `data.table` with a little more work.

First, let's find all of the rows we need to work with.

```r
library(dplyr)
focal %>%
  mutate(HMS = lubridate::hms(HMS)) %>%
  filter(Setting %in% c("Out_Sight", "In_Sight", "End_Focal")) %>%
  group_by(ObsID) %>%
  mutate(outofsight = cumsum(Setting == "Out_Sight")) %>%
  select(ObsID, outofsight, Time, HMS, Setting)
# # A tibble: 37 × 5
# # Groups:   ObsID [6]
#    ObsID outofsight Time     HMS         Setting  
#    <int>      <int> <chr>    <Period>    <chr>    
#  1   548          1 13:00:26 13H 0M 26S  Out_Sight
#  2   548          1 15:08:59 15H 8M 59S  End_Focal
#  3  1535          0 11:12:35 11H 12M 35S End_Focal
#  4  1731          1 8:15:20  8H 15M 20S  Out_Sight
#  5  1731          1 8:15:31  8H 15M 31S  In_Sight 
#  6  1731          2 8:15:47  8H 15M 47S  Out_Sight
#  7  1731          2 8:22:59  8H 22M 59S  In_Sight 
#  8  1731          3 8:30:31  8H 30M 31S  Out_Sight
#  9  1731          3 8:31:11  8H 31M 11S  In_Sight 
# 10  1731          4 8:32:27  8H 32M 27S  Out_Sight
# # … with 27 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The `outofsight` variable is a second grouping variable, where we are assured that the first row of each `ObsID, outofsight`, where:

- if the first row is `"Out_Sight"` and there are two or more rows, then we want the time span between the first and last rows;
- if the first row is `"Out_Sight"` and there is only one row, then we do not see an ending setting, so we will discard that group;
- if the first row is not `"Out_Sight"`, then that `ObsID` never experienced out-of-sight, so we will discard that group.

With that, we can add some summarizing:

```r
focal %>%
  mutate(HMS = lubridate::hms(HMS)) %>%
  filter(Setting %in% c("Out_Sight", "In_Sight", "End_Focal")) %>%
  group_by(ObsID) %>%
  mutate(outofsight = cumsum(Setting == "Out_Sight")) %>%
  select(ObsID, outofsight, Time, HMS, Setting) %>%
  group_by(ObsID, outofsight) %>%
  filter(first(Setting) == "Out_Sight", any(Setting %in% c("In_Sight", "End_Focal"))) %>%
  summarize(time = last(HMS) - first(HMS)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 16 × 3
#    ObsID outofsight time     
#    <int>      <int> <Period> 
#  1   548          1 2H 8M 33S
#  2  1731          1 11S      
#  3  1731          2 7M 12S   
#  4  1731          3 1M -20S  
#  5  1731          4 22S      
#  6  1731          5 31S      
#  7  1731          6 21S      
#  8  1731          7 1M -15S  
#  9  1731          8 1M 13S   
# 10  1731          9 2M 28S   
# 11  3097          1 3M -29S  
# 12  3097          2 12M 36S  
# 13  3100          1 9M 43S   
# 14  3440          1 27S      
# 15  3440          2 29S      
# 16  3440          3 11M -1S
```

Personally, I prefer seconds for this instead of periods, so changing the last line to:

```r
... %>%
  summarize(secs = period_to_seconds(last(HMS) - first(HMS)))
# # A tibble: 16 × 3
# # Groups:   ObsID [5]
#    ObsID outofsight  secs
#    <int>      <int> <dbl>
#  1   548          1  7713
#  2  1731          1    11
#  3  1731          2   432
#  4  1731          3    40
#  5  1731          4    22
#  6  1731          5    31
#  7  1731          6    21
#  8  1731          7    45
#  9  1731          8    73
# 10  1731          9   148
# 11  3097          1   151
# 12  3097          2   756
# 13  3100          1   583
# 14  3440          1    27
# 15  3440          2    29
# 16  3440          3   659
```

Here we have the length of each out-of-sight period (one or more) for each `ObsID` that has any out-of-sight. You can sum these with just a little more:

```r
focal %>%
  mutate(HMS = lubridate::hms(HMS)) %>%
  filter(Setting %in% c("Out_Sight", "In_Sight", "End_Focal")) %>%
  group_by(ObsID) %>%
  mutate(outofsight = cumsum(Setting == "Out_Sight")) %>%
  select(ObsID, outofsight, Time, HMS, Setting) %>%
  group_by(ObsID, outofsight) %>%
  filter(first(Setting) == "Out_Sight", any(Setting %in% c("In_Sight", "End_Focal"))) %>%
  summarize(secs = period_to_seconds(last(HMS) - first(HMS))) %>%
  group_by(ObsID) %>%
  summarize(secs = sum(secs))
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   ObsID  secs
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1   548  7713
# 2  1731   823
# 3  3097   907
# 4  3100   583
# 5  3440   715
```

Comment: Thank you r2evans, that's a nicely efficient solution! :)